# Zariski and Euclidean topologies

Tags: general-topology, geometry, zariski-topology

I've shown that every open set in the Zariski topology is open in the Euclidean topology, but I wonder why they are not equivalent. I'm searching for an open set in the Euclidean topology that is not open in Zariski.

Comment: Please provide more context and share your own thoughts. What's the space/variety you're considering?

Comment: The Zariski topology is usually not (never?) Hausdorff, so it is certainly not equivalent to the Euclidean topology.

Comment: @Christoph I'm sorry, I'm considering $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $n\geq 1$

Comment: This boils down to: Find a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ that is not the zero set of a system of polynomial equations and take the complement. I'm sure you'll find one.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  Consider the affine line $\mathbb{R}$, and let $U = \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you. It  seems to work also $\mathbb{R}^n/ \mathbb{Z}^n$, right?